# como gravar no monolog o resultado do var_dump($_FILES);

Tags: php, symfony

Estou precisando salvar no monolog os registro do var_dump($file) para identificar um erro.
Não sei como proceder. Meu monolog em app\config

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: 'rotating_file'
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/producao.log"
            level: debug
            channels: [!event]
        console:
            type:   console
            channels: [!event, !doctrine]
```

Comment: Se vc quer gravar a saida do `var_dump()`, use a função `var_export()` ex: `$resultado = var_export($var, true);`

Comment: E tem como colocar isso para funcionar no monolog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso você esteja dentro de um controller, basta pegar o serviço `logger` e usá-lo para gravar registro no arquivo de logs:

```
$logger = $this->get('logger');
$logger->info(var_dump($var, true));
```

Se você estiver tentando gravar um log dentro de um serviço, você precisa injetar o `logger` dentro dele e depois usá-lo da mesma forma como se fosse em um controller. Segue um exemplo de implementação.

Arquivo `services.yml`:

```
services:
    app.services.my_service:
        arguments: [ "@logger" ]
        class: AppBundle\Services\MyService
```

Classe `AppBundle\Services\MyService`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Services;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class MyService
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}
```